# Django CBV Authentication login/logout solution

Tags: django, authentication, logout, django-class-based-views

I got the CBV setup to login from going to URL "/" of my Django website, but I was trying to get the login to redirect to the URL "/blah/" after successful login.

This is my myapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from content import views as content_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('content.urls')),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-z0-9]+)/$', content_views.BlahDetailView.as_view(), name='blah_detail'),]
```

Here is my content/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url    
from . import views

app_name = 'content'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexList.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

Here is content/views.py

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    """
    Provides the ability to login as a user with a username and password
    """
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'content/login.html'

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password'))
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Sets a test cookie to make sure the user has cookies enabled
        request.session.set_test_cookie()
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
        # If the test cookie worked, go ahead and
        # delete it since its no longer needed
        if self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            self.request.session.delete_test_cookie()
        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        redirect_to = self.request.GET.get(self.redirect_field_name)
        if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=self.request.get_host()):
            redirect_to = self.success_url
        return redirect_to


class LogoutView(RedirectView):
    """
    Provides users the ability to logout
    """
    url = '/login/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            auth_logout(request)
        return super(LogoutView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class IndexList(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'content/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'home_page'
    queryset = <some object>

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_active:
            return super(IndexList, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, self.request.path))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            context['authenticated_user'] = True
        else:
            context['authenticated_user'] = False
        <<some other context data here>>
        return context

class BlahDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Obj
    template_name = 'content/blah'
    context_object_name = 'blah_detail'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_active:
            return super(BlahDetailView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('?next=%s' % (self.request.path))

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.page = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Obj.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'], enabled=True).order_by('name')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlahDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            context['authenticated_user'] = True
        else:
            context['authenticated_user'] = False
        << some other context data here>>
        return context
```

And this is the content/login.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'content:login' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

When I go to "/" it opens the login page, then I log in and it redirects to the "/". But when I go to "/blah/" it opens the login page, but it does not redirect to "/blah/". I see that I have success_url set to "/", I just don't understand how I can redirect it to "/blah/" or if I go to any other url. I am a newbie, so I apologize if I am not seeing something self evident. Thanks --simi